Photon Fusion VR - Networked Object Not Syncing?
I'm using Photon Fusion, Shared mode, and I have 2 scenes: Login & Session. I'm able to get both a Quest 2 and 3 headset into the same shared VR session, and see a simple avatar of both players (box) that syncs well, and even share audio (photon voice). That's all working great. What I've been struggling to get for days is properly networked objects. I've tried everything. I have a simple game object in my Session scene, (called BladeA) with a Network Object and Network Transform component. I save this object so it's registered properly. It also has a box collider & rigidbody, and a tag 3D_Objects.
To "grab" this in VR I then have a simple script attached to a VR controller, which is supposed to detect OnTriggerEnter and then update the network transform of the BladeA so it's sort of "glued" to the controller. This is also working fine - except from the perspective of the other player (in VR) the position of BladeA does not change at all. I've even added a TextMeshPro in a canvas with a script to list all the Networked ObjectIDs, and the BladeA has the same ID for both clients (headsets).
Why do you think the position of BladeA is not synced for each user?
This script is attached to a child object on each VR hand controller:
using UnityEngine;
using Fusion;

public class SphereTriggerLogger : NetworkBehaviour
{
    private NetworkObject intersectedNetworkObject; // Store the intersected NetworkObject
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("3D_Objects"))
        {
            NetworkObject netObj = other.GetComponent<NetworkObject>();
            if (netObj != null)
            {
                intersectedNetworkObject = netObj; // Store the intersected NetworkObject
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("3D_Objects"))
        {
            NetworkObject netObj = other.GetComponent<NetworkObject>();
            if (netObj != null && netObj == intersectedNetworkObject)
            {
                intersectedNetworkObject = null; // Clear the reference when the object exits
            }
        }
    }

    public override void FixedUpdateNetwork()
    {
        if (intersectedNetworkObject != null)
        {
            NetworkTransform networkTransform = intersectedNetworkObject.GetComponent<NetworkTransform>();

            // Update the NetworkTransform to match the sphere's transform
            networkTransform.transform.position = transform.position;
            networkTransform.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;
        }
    }
}


Here is what I suspect the problem might be:
(not sure how to fix it though).
I suspect that both clients see their own instance of BladeA since it is loaded into the scene from the start, even though both users agree to the same InstanceID for BladeA. And each client has Authority over their own instance (??), but not the other user's instance. But there are still some holes in my theory. I just can't figure this one out.

Afaik objects that already pre-existed in the scene are automatically owned by the master client. Transferring ownership in Shared Mode seems to be explained here .. as a first step you would need to enable Allow State Authority Override and then accordingly release and request authority
